# What's the difference between hardware and software interrupt?

Tags: task-scheduler, interrupts

I'm gonna sketch my understanding of both. I've googled around but i'm not sure about my knowledge. **Please correct me!**

Hardware interrupt is generated by the operation system event scheduler to reassign the cpu time for another process. Is this true?

Software interrupt can be generated from a running program who wants for example to read a file, and for that we need to reassign the cpu for the appropriate operation system call. Is this true?

Is there other kind of software/hardware interrupts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hardware and software interrupts primarily differ by how they're generated: hardware interrupts are generated by hardware, e.g. a timer, keyboard, network card etc while software interrupts are triggered by a special software instruction (e.g. `int 0x80`). There is also a related difference in their role: hardware interrupt handlers are supposed to handle hardware events (e.g. a packet arriving on a network interface) while software handlers are supposed to serve another piece of software, usually an application, which executed the interrupt instruction (e.g. in order to request the kernel to access a file on application's behalf).

Timer interrupt is indeed used by operating system's scheduler to periodically regain control and perform various operations (e.g. resource accounting, context switches).

Generating a software interrupt is one way of communicating with the kernel and may be used on some platforms to invoke system calls.